# calculating partial derivatives on piece wise function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $$g(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy+xz+yz}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)}, & \text{if } xi+yj+zk \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if } xi+yj+zk = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

calculate $\partial_xg(0)$,$\partial_yg(0)$, and $\partial_zg(0)$ if they exist

I'm not sure where to plug in 0 to see which equation to derive for.

Comment: typo? should that be $xi+yj+zk = 0$ instead?

Comment: No, the question is exact

Comment: what are $i$, $j$ and $k$? unit vectors along $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes? in that case $xi+yj+xk = 0$ seems redundant.

Comment: I'm guessing you're saying that because it results in 0 for all partials like the answer below? But yes the question is exactly how I wrote it.

Comment: No i was observing that $xi + yj=0 \iff x=y=0$. If $x,y=0$, then $xi+yj+xk=0$. So the final term isn't required.

Comment: ohhhhh yea that is definitely a z. but yea it was redundant if that were the case

Comment: :) Sometimes it's better just to write $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$
\partial_xg(0,0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x,0,0)-g(0,0,0)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0+0+0}{x\sqrt {x^2+0+0}}=0.
$$
Same calculations for the other $\partial$s.